# How to group a JSON array of objects together

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file which has an array of objects under 'delivery_options'.

https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m

Currently, I am extracting this data using .each

```
                $.each(value.delivery_options, function(key, val) {
                        $('#del-options').append('<li del-id='+ key +'  class="list-group-item del-options link-class"><div> ' + val.name + ' </div><div> ' + val.description + ' </div><div class=""> ' + val.price + ' </div></li>');
                })
```

My issue with this is, it's printing all the delivery options under one list `<ul> </ul>` instead of breaking them up into multiple lists `<ul> </ul> <ul> </ul> <ul> </ul>`

below is the full jquery I am using.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('#search').blur(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#lat-long').html('');
        $('#opening-times').html('');
        $('#del-options').html('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
            //console.log('json')
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                if (value.address.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.line1.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.town.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.county.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1) {
                //console.log(value)
                    //COURIER ADDRESS DETAILS
                    $('#result').append('<li data-contentid='+ key +' class="list-group-item courier"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="address"> ' + value.address.name + ',' + value.address.line1 + ',' + value.address.town + ',' + value.address.county + ',' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
                    //LAT AND LONG

                    var mapProp= {
                        center:new google.maps.LatLng(value.location.latitude,value.location.longitude),
                        zoom:5,
                        };
                    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);



                    //OPENING TIMES
                    $('#opening-times').append('<li id=open-times-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item op-times"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> Opening Times </div><div class="">Mon ' + value.opening_times.Mon + ' </div><div class="">Tues ' + value.opening_times.Tues + ' </div><div class="">Wed ' + value.opening_times.Wed + ' </div><div class="">Thurs ' + value.opening_times.Thurs + ' </div><div class="">Fri ' + value.opening_times.Fri + ' </div><div class="">Sat ' + value.opening_times.Sat + ' </div><div class="">Sun ' + value.opening_times.Sun + ' </div></li>');
                    // ARRAY DELIVERY OPTIONS
                    $.each(value.delivery_options, function(key, val) {
                            $('#del-options').append('<li del-id='+ key +'  class="list-group-item del-options link-class"><div> ' + val.name + ' </div><div> ' + val.description + ' </div><div class=""> ' + val.price + ' </div></li>');
                    })

                    //COURIER ADDRESS FOR OTHER CONTAINER
                    $('#address-container').append('<li id=cour-add-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item alt-address link-class"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.line1 + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.town + '</div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.county + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is a screenshot to help show the issue. As you can see 0 - 5 should be in one list and then another 0 - 5 in another list.

https://snag.gy/g2Dtqd.jpg

Any assistance or tips would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the markup to

```
<div id="del-lists-wrapper"></div>
```

and then the js to something like

```
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
$.each(value.delivery_options, function(key, val) {
    ul.append('<li del-id=' + key + '  class="list-group-item del-options link-class"><div> ' + val.name + ' </div><div> ' + val.description + ' </div><div class=""> ' + val.price + ' </div></li>');
});
ul.appendTo('#del-lists-wrapper');
```

So your whole code as above would be

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
$('#search').blur(function() {
    $('#result').html('');
    $('#lat-long').html('');
    $('#opening-times').html('');
    $('#del-options').html('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
        //console.log('json')
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            if (value.address.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.line1.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.town.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.county.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1) {
            //console.log(value)
                //COURIER ADDRESS DETAILS
                $('#result').append('<li data-contentid='+ key +' class="list-group-item courier"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="address"> ' + value.address.name + ',' + value.address.line1 + ',' + value.address.town + ',' + value.address.county + ',' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
                //LAT AND LONG

                var mapProp= {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(value.location.latitude,value.location.longitude),
                    zoom:5,
                    };
                var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);



                //OPENING TIMES
                $('#opening-times').append('<li id=open-times-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item op-times"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> Opening Times </div><div class="">Mon ' + value.opening_times.Mon + ' </div><div class="">Tues ' + value.opening_times.Tues + ' </div><div class="">Wed ' + value.opening_times.Wed + ' </div><div class="">Thurs ' + value.opening_times.Thurs + ' </div><div class="">Fri ' + value.opening_times.Fri + ' </div><div class="">Sat ' + value.opening_times.Sat + ' </div><div class="">Sun ' + value.opening_times.Sun + ' </div></li>');
                // ARRAY DELIVERY OPTIONS
                var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
                $.each(value.delivery_options, function(key, val) {
                    ul.append('<li del-id=' + key + '  class="list-group-item del-options link-class"><div> ' + val.name + ' </div><div> ' + val.description + ' </div><div class=""> ' + val.price + ' </div></li>');
                });
                ul.appendTo('#del-lists-wrapper');

                //COURIER ADDRESS FOR OTHER CONTAINER
                $('#address-container').append('<li id=cour-add-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item alt-address link-class"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.line1 + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.town + '</div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.county + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This puts them into separate lists which is great - but now is extracting all the delivery options instead of only displaying the delivery options for the correct ID - any ideas?

Comment: You still need the rest of the code in there. So it still needs to be in the if statement. I'll update the answer so it's easier for you.

Comment: I had it in the right position. I just had the .each function twice. Thanks a lot - I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah soz I just realised that first answer wasn't as clear as it could have been and you couldn't just drop in the code so I removed that first loop cuz you already have it and I just updated your own code so it worked 'out the box' as it were. Glad I could help :)